# Creating a for loop for showing dynamic data

Tags: php, wordpress, function, for-loop

I'm currently developing a custom WordPress template. Within this template I'm trying to show all post from specific categories, see it as a sort of products segment (no selling or anything). So what I've got now is showing all posts image and title dynamically with all the styling and filtering through settings of [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

What I would like to achieve is the following result: (using bootstrap).

4 columns on each row, but when there are more than 4 posts. (so when there needs to be a second or third row of a specific category), Create a collapse functionality for showing posts 5 >.

So after some trying, I've come to the conclusion that the best way would be to create a for loop, in combination with filtering this would create the view I'm trying to create. Sadly after trying some different methods, I've got a bit stuck. The code is shown below:

```
<div id="items">
<?php

    if (have_rows('products_category')) {

        while (have_rows('products_category')) : the_row();

        // Your loop code
        $title = get_sub_field('product_category_name');
        $slug = get_sub_field('product_category_slug');

        /* Start the filter categpries segment */
        $category = get_category_by_slug($slug);
        $filter_id = $category->term_id;
        $filters = array();
        var_dump($filters);
        array_push($filters, $filter_id);
        var_dump($filters);
        array_push($filters, 7);
        var_dump($filters);

        ?>
        <div id="items" class="row products margin-0 justify-content-between">
            <div class=" <?php echo $filter_id ?> ">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0 padding-b-10">
                    <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 padding-0">
                    <div id="products" class="row products margin-0 justify-content-between">
                        <?php $argsNew = array(
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'category' => $filters,
                            'orderby' => 'date',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'include' => '',
                            'exclude' => '',
                            'meta_key' => '',
                            'meta_value' => '',
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'post_mime_type' => '',
                            'post_parent' => '',
                            'author' => '',
                            'author_name' => '',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'suppress_filters' => false,
                            'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
                        );
                        $posts_array = get_posts($argsNew);
                        $number_posts = count($posts_array);
                        echo $number_posts;
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($posts_array as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                        $i++;
                        if($i <= 4) {
                        ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-fix padding-s-15 padding-b-30 image_filter">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive big_image products_image img_small')); ?>
                                <?php the_title(sprintf('<h2 class="text-center big_image_product_text products_text"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url(get_permalink())),
                                    '</a></h2>'); ?>
                                <?php

                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                                else if($i > 4) {
                                    ?>
                    </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button data-toggle="collapse" class="btn-collapse" data-target="#products_collapse_<?php echo $filter_id ?>">Show more</button>
                        </div>
                    <div id="products_collapse_<?php echo $filter_id ?>" class="row products collapse margin-0 justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-fix padding-s-15 padding-b-30 image_filter">
                            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive big_image products_image img_small')); ?>
                            <?php the_title(sprintf('<h2 class="text-center big_image_product_text products_text"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url(get_permalink())),
                                '</a></h2>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <?php
                        }
                        endforeach;
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php
        endwhile;
        }
        else {
        // no rows found
            echo "nothing found!";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried creating the for loop with the `$number_posts` and a count method but sadly then the view is badly corrupted. So my question is:

1. Create a for loop / counter to count the number of posts foreach category shown.
2. Specify the view on those results:

for -> items 1,2,3,4. Place them in a row. (1 1 1 1).
if(more than 4 items). Place items > 5 (and so on). Under a collapse block.

e.g.

**3 items:**

```
Normal view: 

1 1 1.
```

**7 items:**

view + collapse (

```
 1 1 1 1 
 -collapse button-
 1 1 1 
(more items)
```

)

Could anyone show me in the right direction and or help me with this one?
Thanks in advance!

PS: If you have any questions please ask them in the comments below

Comment: What is the need for ACF, you can loop through categories without it?

Comment: The need for ACF is because the client wants to choose specificly what to show and wha not to show. It's a dynamic build up because it was requested this way. @Ali_k

Comment: Ok, is there a way you can return an array of the specified categories in ACF.

Comment: Can you use var_dump() on this and let me know the result: `$specified_cats = get_field( "products_category" );`

Comment: Yes but i think you're asking the wrong questions due to that i need to update my question more, so i've just updated my question above to make it more clear @Ali_k

Comment: I understand your question, but there is another approach to this, and I need to know the answer to my question above to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the field `products_category` returns an array of chosen category IDs:
[image]
This will work:

```
<div id="items">
<?php
    // Retrieve all product categories
    $terms = get_terms( 'product_cat' );
    // Retrieve chosen categories to display 
    $specified_cats = get_field( "products_category" );

    // Loop though product cats
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $filter_id = $term->term_id;
        // If the current product category id is not in the array 'specified_cats' just to the next iteration
        if(!in_array($filter_id, $specified_cats)){
            continue;
        }

        $title = $term->name;
        $slug = $term->slug;


       ?>
        <div id="items" class="row products margin-0 justify-content-between">
            <div class=" <?php echo $filter_id ?> ">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padding-0 padding-b-10">
                    <h2><?php echo $title ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12 padding-0">
                    <div id="products" class="row products margin-0 justify-content-between">
                        <?php 
                        $argsNew = array (
                            'offset' => 0,
                            'orderby' => 'date',
                            'order' => 'DESC',
                            'post_type' => 'product',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1,
                            'product_cat'=> $term->name
                        ); 

                        $posts_array = get_posts($argsNew);
                        $number_posts = count($posts_array);
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($posts_array as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
                        $i++;
                        if($i <= 4) {
                        ?>
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-fix padding-s-15 padding-b-30 image_filter">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive big_image products_image img_small')); ?>
                                <?php the_title(sprintf('<h2 class="text-center big_image_product_text products_text"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url(get_permalink())),
                                    '</a></h2>'); ?>
                                <?php

                                ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                            }else if($i > 4) {
                                    ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <button data-toggle="collapse" class="btn-collapse" data-target="#products_collapse_<?php echo $filter_id ?>">Show more</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="products_collapse_<?php echo $filter_id ?>" class="row products collapse margin-0 justify-content-between">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 margin-fix padding-s-15 padding-b-30 image_filter">
                                <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, '', array('class' => 'img-responsive big_image products_image img_small')); ?>
                                <?php the_title(sprintf('<h2 class="text-center big_image_product_text products_text"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url(get_permalink())),
                                    '</a></h2>'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        }
                        endforeach;
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

?>
</div>
```

The code is tested and working. I even included Bootstrap to make sure everything functioning correctly:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```